# Is there a way to refresh appengine logs more quickly?

Tags: google-app-engine

**Is there a way to make logs in the admin console refresh more quickly?**
Mine seem to take over 30 mins to refresh.

I vaguely remember reading about a setting somewhere, but for the life of me I can't recall where exactly.

I guess there is a performance penalty for refreshing too fast. Even so, a frequency of 30 mins is too high. Something like 5 mins would be more useful.

Comment: Duplicate (although he posted after you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968933/how-to-see-fresh-logs-in-appengine-dashboard/8969263

Comment: Thanks @AbhranilDas. Atleast now I know that I am not alone in this situation.