# How to see fresh logs in appengine dashboard?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I'm using AppEngine for some small web application. However, the logs I see in the [appengine dashboard](https://appengine.google.com) are always 30 mins to a few hours old. Is there any way to see "fresher" logs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that changing the timezone to PST shows the freshest logs.

Answer (score 1):

I have an appengine app and there too the latest log now is 33 mins old. I suspect it takes a while for events to get there. It appears to me there can't be a way to modify this. But make sure first that you choose the correct Time Zone from the dropdown menu. I noticed it affects the time of the latest log.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the correct Timezone". I do choose my own timezone - does it actually affect *which* messages you see, not only their associated timestamp?

Comment: It affects only the timestamp. For example, my timezone was wrong by default, and the latest event was 1 hr 17 minutes ago. After I fixed my time zone, I saw it was actually 33 mins ago.

Comment: Thanks, so I'm wondering whether it's possible to get those 33 mins to be lower...

Answer (score 1):

This might be a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5494) in Google App Engine.

Here is a workaround taken from [this response](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5494#c2) in the previous link:

[image: 'Now' is displaying logs from ~30 minutes ago]

[image: Selecting a date still does not fix the problem]

[image: Manually adding +1 hour seems to fix the issue]